# How to update each item in gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I want update each item in GridView

[GridView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZUwy.jpg)

after update will be like this

[Gridview after update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKPXk.jpg)

i have tried   **View tempviewi  = gridviewAdapteri.getView(i,null,gridview)**   and after this  **(TextView)tempviewi.findViewById(R.id.txtItem)**   i can read textview its ok, but when i setText there is nothing

This is my custom adapter

```
 @Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View itemView = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (itemView == null)
    {
        final LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(resourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imgItem = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.MainPic);
        holder.imgInd = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.PowerInd);
        holder.txtItem = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtItem);
        holder.txtAddress = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.texthide);

        itemView.setTag(holder);

    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) itemView.getTag();
    }


    TitoRow item = getItem(position);

    holder.imgItem.setImageDrawable(item.getImage());

    holder.txtItem.setText(item.getTitle());

    holder.txtAddress.setText(item.getAddress());

    holder.imgInd.setImageDrawable(item.GetInd());

    return itemView;
}
```

Comment: Please make sure your item's title not empty

Comment: items not empty, i can ready each item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your item title and call *notifyDataSetChanged()* on your adapter

Edit:

```
ArrayList<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<Item>();
itemList.add(new Item("title 1"));
itemList.add(new Item("title 2"));

YourCustomAdapter adapter = new YourCustomAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.your_layout_item, itemList);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

//...

//modify item
itemList.get(0).setTitle("New Title");
//call notifyDataSetChanged
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks for answers!i just add notifyDataSetChanged() after modify but same. i think  problem in modify code

Comment: Thank you! Now i understand how does this work, you save me hours. i make changes and it works :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use notifyDataSetChanged() each time you want to update your gridview.

Comment: Thank you! just solved problem with notifyDataSetChanged

Answer (score 0):

Create One Model Class For Grid Items Like Title And Image

```
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

Then in Your ArrayAdapter GetView Method Add this

```
    YourArrayAdapterClass item = data.get(position);
    holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.ivGrid.setImageResource(item.getImage());
    return row;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! but i just have this code in my GetView, you can found this code in my post, but my main question is how modify items from activity

Comment: create arraylist of your model class then use the add method and set Your Adapter and do adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: I already make this and it works :) Problem solved with this method. Thank you